# Can't access two tables on a single database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a problem with SQLiteAssetHelper (https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper): I cant open the tables in my database correctly.

The database is made using sqlitebrowser.
I have a database with two tables filled with strings which I want to access with a Cursor, but when I try to access them both, it gives me an error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Verbs (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT LatinVerbs FROM Verbs WHERE _rowid_=?
```

My database contract:

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class DatabaseContract {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "verbtable.db";
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";

    private DatabaseContract(){}
    public static abstract class Table1 implements BaseColumns{
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Verbs";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL1 = "LatinVerbs";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL2 = "Translation";
        public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL1 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL2 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        " )";
        public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

    }
    public static abstract class Table2 implements BaseColumns{
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Structure";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL1 = "infinitive";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL2 = "pers_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL3 = "ind_praes_act";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL4 = "ind_praes_pass";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL5 = "ind_impf_act";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL6 = "ind_impf_pass";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL7 = "ind_fut_act";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL8 = "ind_fut_pass";
        public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL1 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL2 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL3 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL4 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL5 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL6 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL7 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL8 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                        " )";
        public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    }
}
```

My Cursors:

```
Cursor c = db.query(DatabaseContract.Table1.TABLE_NAME, columns, "_rowid_=?", selectionArgsRoot, null, null, null);

int index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columns[0]);
c.moveToFirst();
do {
    rootResult = c.getString(index);
 } while (c.moveToNext());

c.close();

c = db.query(DatabaseContract.Table2.TABLE_NAME, columnSuffix, "pers_id=?", selectionArgsSuffix, null, null, null);
index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnSuffix[0]);
c.moveToFirst();
do{
    suffix = c.getString(index);
}while(c.moveToNext());
c.close();
```

I tried to update the database version and restarted the emulator I was running my code on, but the error still remains.

Comment: Well, as it says, table "Verbs" does not exist. How did you confirm the tables are created correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever run the program with the database creation before? If you have, you will need to increment your  database version number. This has to be done when you make additions.

You can also try uninstalling the app in the emulator and re-running a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks! uninstalling the app did the trick! I think the emulator didn't notice that the database had changed, because the filename stayed the same, so it kept using the old version on its local memory.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to look into using an Android ORM like SugarORM, ORMLite, GreenDAO, etc. Check it out http://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/

Answer (score 0):

Both the tables **aren't created**.
In facts, you are adding an **extra comma** after the last column, on each table.

Here:

```
COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL2 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
" )";
```

And here:

```
COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL8 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
" )";
```

These lines should actually be:

```
COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL2 + TEXT_TYPE + ")";
```

And:

```
COLUMN_NAME_TITLE_COL8 + TEXT_TYPE + ")";
```

Respectively

Comment: The code on the official site ends with commas as well, so I don't think that might be the problem (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). But thanks for the reply!

Comment: `The code on the official site ends with commas as well, so I don't think that might be the problem ` **The code on the official site DOESN'T end with appended commas**. Read better: `FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
    ... // Any other options for the CREATE command`